# Kusto / Azure Data Explorer - Distinct count in kusto queries

Tags: azure-application-insights, kql

I'm using Application Insights with a customEvent and need to get the number of events with a distinct field.

The event looks something like this:

```
{
    "statusCode" : 200,
    "some_field": "ABC123QWERTY"
}
```

I want the number of unique `some_field` with `statusCode` 200 . I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60778290/kusto-distinct-count) question and tried a couple of different queries. Some of them giving different answers. In SQL it would have looked something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT my_field) AS Count
FROM customEvents
WHERE statusCode=200
```

**Which one is correct?**

### 1 - dcount with default accuracy

```
customEvents
| where (customDimensions.statusCode == 200) and timestamp >= startofday(datetime(2022-12-01T00:00:00Z)) and timestamp <= endofday(datetime(2022-12-31T00:00:00Z))
| summarize dcount(tostring(customDimensions.some_field))
```

**17,853** items

---

### 2 - Count by my_field and count number of rows

```
customEvents
| extend my_field = tostring(customDimensions.some_field)
| where customDimensions.statusCode == 200 and timestamp >= startofday(datetime(2022-12-01T00:00:00Z)) and timestamp <= endofday(datetime(2022-12-31T00:00:00Z))
| summarize Count = count() by my_field
```

**17,774** items.

---

### 3 - summarize with by some_field

```
customEvents
| extend StatusCode = tostring(customDimensions["statusCode"]), MyField = tostring(customDimensions["some_field"])
| where timestamp >= startofday(datetime(2022-12-01T00:00:00Z)) and timestamp <= endofday(datetime(2022-12-31T00:00:00Z))
| summarize any(StatusCode) by MyField
| summarize Count = count() by any_StatusCode
```

**17,626** items.

---

### 4 - dcount with higher accuracy?

```
customEvents
| where (customDimensions.statusCode == 200) and timestamp >= startofday(datetime(2022-12-01T00:00:00Z)) and timestamp <= endofday(datetime(2022-12-31T00:00:00Z))
| summarize dcount(tostring(customDimensions.some_field),4)
```

**17,736** items

---

### 5 - count_distinct from preview

```
customEvents
| where (customDimensions.statusCode == 200) and timestamp >= startofday(datetime(2022-12-01T00:00:00Z)) and timestamp <= endofday(datetime(2022-12-31T00:00:00Z))
| summarize count_distinct(tostring(customDimensions.some_field))
```

**17,744** items

According to the [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuremonitor#dcount-dcountif) it states:

> Use dcount and dcountif to count distinct values in a specific column.

And [dcount-aggfunction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/dcount-aggfunction) mentions the accuracy:

> Returns an **estimate** of the number of distinct values of expr in the group.

[count_distinct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/count-distinct-aggfunction) seems to be the *correct* way:

> Counts unique values specified by the scalar expression per summary group, or the total number of unique values if the summary group is omitted.

Answer (score 0):

`count_distinct()` is a new KQL function that returns an accurate result.

`dcount()` returns an approximate result.
It can be used with a 2nd argument, a constant integer with value 0, 1, 2, 3 or 4 (0 = fast , 1 = default, 2 = accurate, 3 = extra accurate, 4 = super accurate).

1. In your examples (specifically "4 - dcount with higher accuracy?") you have not used a 2nd argument.
2. Higher accuracy means higher accuracy - ***statistically***.
   It means that the error will be bound to a lower value.
   Theoretically (and in practice) dcount() with lower accuracy may yield in some scenarios a result that is closer to the real number than dcount() with higher accuracy.

Having said that -

I would guess that you executed your queries with a UI filter of last 24 hours or something similar.
This means that each execution ran over a different timespan.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. All queries have a specific timespan set (which I now updated the question with). I previously excluded it for readability. Also, I noticed that a type-o was included in the code for *4*. Accuracy was set to level *4*.

Comment: I fail to understand why option 3 gives me another result than option 5 and 2. I *do* understand why _dcount_ gives an estimate, which could explain the difference.

Comment: In option 3 you are not filtering by`customDimensions.statusCode == 200`. Also, the use of `any(StatusCode)` doesn't seem to make much sense.